# 555 Timer @1MHz

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, timer, 555

i am very new to electrical engineering and super unsure what to buy, because this is my first practical project...

**The task:** 
I want to implement a `hardware timer` with ~1MHz frequency for the [HCTL-2022 chip](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/04e5/0900766b804e53e3.pdf). 
For this i would use the [TCL555CP Timer](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/152197-da-01-en-TLC_555_CP.pdf), two resistors with 500 Ohm and 1 kOhm, a capacitor of 1nF and a smoothing capacitor of 10nF as shown in this [wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NE555#Astabile_Kippstufe).

**The usage:** 
The `HCTL-2022` is reading a optical incremental encoder with ~4kppm. I want to read the `HCTL` with the `Arduino Mega 2560`. I need the timer because i think the microcontroller is not able to create a frequency that high.

Is this setup ok for my task? Is there a better / easier way? Can you give me any tips? Do i have to pay attention which capacitor or resistor i am buying?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: "i think the microcontroller is not able to create a frequency that high." Why? Are you running it off a watch crystal?

Comment: i am reading data from the HCTL and transfering them over Serial to a desktop application. because of that i thought it is no possible to hold a frequency of 1 MHz while doing timing relevant operations.

Comment: But that's what the timer peripherals are for.

Comment: While you can get 1 MHz from the TCL555P, please read p.9, "Operating Characteristics", fmax for the component values.

Answer (score 1):

First way to complete your task - give clock for decoder from arduino's hardware timer output. [There is](http://r6500.blogspot.ru/2014/12/fast-pwm-on-arduino-leonardo.html) some low-level code.
Also, you may read app.notes at [atmel.com](http://www.atmel.com/search.aspx?&q=avr+timer+pwm)

Other way - using only arduino, without any additional ICs.
I don't sure about performance, but [this code](http://makeatronics.blogspot.ru/2013/02/efficiently-reading-quadrature-with.html) seems operable. If this code is not fast enougth, you should use bare-metal C language, without arduino libraries.